# How to run sudo su in Azure devops pipeline?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to execute few linux commands as root user in azure devops pipeline.

In server (putty) if we enter sudo su and it will prompt for password and we can enter it. If we dont want this to enter password, we can edit sudo visudo file (and give NOPASSWD).

But, I want to run this in Azure devops pipeline.. when I try to run sudo su in pipeline it will ask for long time without error (keep on running the job) as it may ask for passoword (without prompting)

I have tried with echol "PASSWORD" | sudo -S ls.. which didnt work either Tried maximum possibilities and came here Any idea to achieve this

Comment: is it Microsoft Hosted agent or a self-hosted agent?

Comment: self hosted agent